# Query optimisation - takes so long

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have this query that show turnover of the previous 24 months through the current date.

I'm using SQL SERVER 2008, my problem is that my query takes so long to be executed.

I'm using 2 table  : Etablissement to get store name, and piece to get sum of Turnover of each etablissement.
result : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6yo6.png)

```
select ETAB.ET_ETABLISSEMENT as 'STORE CODE'

[Month-1]=(select CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),sum(gl_totalttcdev)) 
from piece left join ligne on gl_souche=gp_souche and gl_naturepieceg=gp_naturepieceg and gl_numero=gp_numero and gl_indiceg=gp_indiceg 
    left join etabliss as e on gp_etablissement=et_etablissement 
    left join ARTICLE on GL_CODEARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE
    where gp_naturepieceg='FFO' 
    and year(gp_datepiece) = year(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
     and  month(gp_datepiece) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) 
    and gl_typearticle<>''
    and gl_typearticle<>'FI' 
    and ETAB.ET_ETABLISSEMENT =e.ET_ETABLISSEMENT
    and ETAB.ET_LIBELLE =e.ET_LIBELLE
    group by gp_etablissement, et_libelle),

    [Month-2]=(select CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),sum(gl_totalttcdev)) 
    from piece left join ligne on gl_souche=gp_souche and gl_naturepieceg=gp_naturepieceg and gl_numero=gp_numero and gl_indiceg=gp_indiceg left join etabliss as e on gp_etablissement=et_etablissement 
    left join ARTICLE on GL_CODEARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE
    where gp_naturepieceg='FFO' 
    and year(gp_datepiece) = year(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
     and  month(gp_datepiece) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) 
    and gl_typearticle<>''
    and gl_typearticle<>'FI' 
    and ETAB.ET_ETABLISSEMENT =e.ET_ETABLISSEMENT
    and ETAB.ET_LIBELLE =e.ET_LIBELLE
    group by gp_etablissement, et_libelle),

    [Some thing for the other months ..]
    [Month-24]..,

    from ETABLISS ETAB
```

Ther's any solution please to optimise my query ?

Comment: this query looks incomplete, please post everything, along with the EXPLAIN plan and the indexes on your tables

Comment: Yes but we CAN'T help you with a **performance issue** if you don't show anything else than the query. We need to see the table's DDL and the EXPLAIN PLAN. You wont get any answer if you don't show that first, because nobody can answer this in the actual state

Comment: Using proper date logic will help. Syntax like `YEAR(gp_datepiece)` will make the query non-SARGable, which is likely a big performance killer

Comment: Also, a subquery is run once for **every** row, not once for a dataset. As we have no data we have no idea how many rows there are, but I suspect that a bunch of non-SARGable subqueries is adding to my comment above.

Comment: We'll need sample data and expected results to help you with that, @hamza.soufiane . All we have right now is an incomplete query.

Comment: As a helpful hint though, the expressions I highlighted earlier should be written as `AND gp_datepiece >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) AND gp_datepiece < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` That will *probably* give you some performance, but there's still more a lot more work to be done (getting rid of those sub queries would be a good start).

Comment: I'v added a pic of the result and some details

Comment: @hamza.soufiane . . . A scalar subquery that uses `GROUP BY` looks like a bug waiting to happen.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and ask how to write an efficient query.

Comment: Don't post images of data, @hamza.soufiane. Data is text, so please supply it as formatted `text`, or (even better) and DDL and DML statements. We can't use an image of data (we can't copy the data out and start using it), so it doesn't help us help you. We need sample data and expected results too. That image looks like your expected results, but tells us nothing about what your data *really* looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment that doesn't fit in the comments section.

I get that you have multiple queries going on and they are becoming slow. Let's take one at a time. For example:

```
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,2),sum(gl_totalttcdev)) 
from piece 
left join ligne on gl_souche = gp_souche 
               and gl_naturepieceg = gp_naturepieceg and gl_numero=gp_numero 
               and gl_indiceg = gp_indiceg 
left join etabliss as e on gp_etablissement = et_etablissement 
left join ARTICLE on GL_CODEARTICLE = ARTICLE.GA_CODEARTICLE
where gp_naturepieceg = 'FFO' 
  and year(gp_datepiece) = year(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))
  and  month(gp_datepiece) =  MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())) 
  and gl_typearticle <> ''
  and gl_typearticle <> 'FI' 
  and ETAB.ET_ETABLISSEMENT = e.ET_ETABLISSEMENT
  and ETAB.ET_LIBELLE = e.ET_LIBELLE
group by gp_etablissement, et_libelle
```

First of all, in order to optimize it it's critical for us to know where each column is coming from. So... **please** add the prefix for all the columns you are mentioning. We can't really guess the tables for each column.

Answer (score 0):

For every record those 2  functions get  executed, `year(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))` and `MONTH( DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))` it always  gives a constant value , stored those value in a variable and use those variable in query will help to improve the speed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query as written is quite confusing and probably why only one other has even offered a solution.  Now lets try to simplify and clarify what you are asking for.  Correct me if anything is incorrect.

You need a query that shows the totals over the last 13 month period grouped by each
store code. The first month represents the month prior to current and going back 13 months (or 24 as you indicated).

Now your query. You are querying from your ETABLISS table and grouping by the gp_etablisssement, et_libelle.
By doing a google translate of French to English

```
Etablissement = Establishement
Libelle = Wording
```

So I am GUESSING your etablissement is more of an ID key that is unique and the Libelle is the label to be shown for the given etablissement.

```
Ex: 
etablissement   libelle
1               Business A
2               Business B
3               Business C
```

So the label will always be a direct correlation with the etablissement (ID) field.

Lets first simplify.  You want a sum of all linge values that qualify per etablissement with some filters.  Start with that, and the piece table is the basis of the date range criteria.  The Piece table has the etablissement field you ultimately want to group by

```
select
        p.gp_etablissement,
        sum(l.gl_totalttcdev) SumPerEtablissement
    from
        Piece P
            JOIN Linge L
                -- all criteria specifically limiting the LINGE records
                on P.gp_souche = L.gl_souche 
                and p.gp_naturepieceg = l.gl_naturepieceg 
                and p.gp_numero = l.gl_numero
                and p.gp_indiceg = l.gl_indiceg
                and l.gl_typearticle <> ''
                and l.gl_typearticle <> 'FI' 
    where
        -- simple to get all records for past 13 months for now just to show summary
        p.gp_DatePiece > dateadd( month, -13, getdate())
    group by
        p.gp_etablissement
```

So from above, we have one result table per establishement with its total over the entire 13 months. Now, you want it broken down per month... add an extra column showing the month/year as a column and group by.  While we are here, we can join to the etablissement table to pull the description/label you may want to show.

One extra item I am throwing into this is the months difference from the current date so we always have a constant sequence to organize totals by.  Use DateDiff().  This will help for your pivot result pulling all data on one row per etablissement.

```
select
        p.gp_etablissement,
        e.et_libelle,
        -- Example: 2019-04-27 would return '2019-04-27'
        CONVERT(CHAR(7),p.gp_DatePiece,120) as YrMonth,
        -- nice thing about datediff by month.  It properly detects
        -- '2019-04-01' from '2019-03-31' as 1 month apart even though 1 day
        -- so ANY Date within the YrMonth will be within the given month.
        min( datediff( month, p.gp_DatePiece, getdate() )) as MonthsPrior,
        -- now the column getting summed
        sum(l.gl_totalttcdev) SumPerEtabliss
    from
        Piece P
            JOIN Linge L
                -- all criteria specifically limiting the LINGE records
                on P.gp_souche = L.gl_souche 
                and p.gp_naturepieceg = l.gl_naturepieceg 
                and p.gp_numero = l.gl_numero
                and p.gp_indiceg = l.gl_indiceg
                and l.gl_typearticle <> ''
                and l.gl_typearticle <> 'FI' 
            JOIN Etabliss e
                on p.gp_etablissement = e.et_etablissement
    where
        -- simple to get all records for past 13 months for now just to 
        -- show summary, or change to 24 months as so needed
        p.gp_DatePiece > dateadd( month, -13, getdate())
    group by
        p.gp_etablissement,
        e.et_libelle,
        CONVERT(CHAR(7),GETDATE(),120)
```

the above results may have something like...

```
gp_etablissement  et_libelle   YrMonth   MonthsPrior   SumPerEtabliss
establissID1      libell1      2018-12   4             382
establissID1      libell1      2019-01   3             123
establissID1      libell1      2019-02   2             821
establissID1      libell1      2019-03   1             467

establissID2      libell2      2018-12   4             532
establissID2      libell2      2019-01   3             221
establissID2      libell2      2019-02   2             629
establissID2      libell2      2019-03   1             395
```

Now, you can build a cross-tab query aggregating each column based on how many month away they are from the original month in question.  Since you want 24 months, you would have to copy/paste the sum() values below to represent the remaining columns.

```
select
        pq.gp_etablissement,
        pq.et_libelle,
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 1],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 2],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 3 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 3],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 4 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 4],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 5 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 5],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 6 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 6],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 7 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 7],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 8 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 8],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 9 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 9],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 10 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 10],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 11 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 11],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 12 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 12],
        sum( pq.SumPerEtabliss * case when pq.MonthsPrior = 13 then 1 else 0 end ) as [Month 13]
    from
        ( THE ENTIRE QUERY ABOVE THAT DOES THE GROUP BY ) PQ
    group by
        pq.gp_etablissement,
        pq.et_libelle
    order by
        pq.et_libelle
```